# Unity app with Firebase works in editor but no longer connecting during build

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, virtual-reality, openxr

I am making a VR application using Unity with OpenXR, and have it connected to Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database. It was initially working fine on both editor and on build on a Meta Quest 2, but we had to change our database. After changing the database, I replaced the google-services.json with the new one in the same location. In the editor, I can connect to Firebase fine but when I build and try in VR, I am unable to connect.

I've tried re-adding the google-services.json and removing and re-installing the Firebase Unity SDK's manually. I even saw on another post that you can create the app options manually as a last resort and tried that using the following code, but it still doesn't work.
[Manual App Options Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kizMh.png)

Would really appreciate the help, been stuck on this for a long time now!

Comment: Do you have both google-services.json files handy? If you diff them, is the database the only thing that has changed? Have you investigated your build logs for any warnings or errors? Are there any runtime errors you run into? Are you running a clean build or an incremental build?

Comment: Yes, the database URL was the only difference and no errors or stack trace was showing up when testing in editor as it was working fine. It was just getting stuck when I actually built to the VR headset. I ended up remaking another Firebase project and re-importing to the Unity project and that actually ended up fixing the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out!